# What is the proper way to make a join query in mariadb?

Tags: mariadb

I have a two table in the database, **companies** and **line_of_business**, I'd like to get all data from the table **companies** together with a **line_of_business** column in the table **type_of_business**.

This are the fields for the table companies:

```
id,
company,
address,
city,
tel_number,
fax_number,
line_of_business(FRK)
```

And this are the fields for the table line_of_business:

```
id,
type_of_business,
description
```

I tried to make a query on the database with the reference from here. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp, but the result is `#1054 - Unknown column 'companies.company' in 'field list',` which there exist a company column in the table **companies**

Here's the query I made,

```
SELECT `companies.id`, `companies.company`, `companies.address`, `companies.city`, `companies.tel_number`, `companies.fax_number`, `companies.tax_number`, `line_of_business.type_of_business` FROM `companies` INNER JOIN `line_of_business` ON `line_of_business.id`=`companies.line_of_business`
```

Any idea of the proper way to make a join query?

Comment: \`line_of_business.id\` your back ticks make the db interpret a table and a column as  1 column,use \`line_of_business\`.\`id\`

Comment: Oh yeah thank for that It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `companies`.`company` instead `companies.company` for all column